# Detect first line of text file separately?

Tags: java

I am designing a program that will load a text file into different media file classes (Media > Audio > mp3, Media > Video > Avi, etc).
Now the first line of my text file is how many files there are in total, as in

```
    3
    exmaple.mp3,fawg,gseges
    test.gif,wfwa,rgeg 
    ayylmao.avi,awf,gesg
```

Now that is what is in my text file, I want to first get the first line separately, then loop through the rest of the files.
Now I understand I can simply count how many files are in by using an int that grows as I loop but I want it clear in the file aswell, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
static public Media[] importMedia(String fileName)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null)
            {
                //Get the first line of the text file seperatly? (Then maybe remove it? idk)
                //Split string, create a temp media file and add it to a list for the rest of the lines
            }
            //String[] split = s.next().split(",");
        } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
        return null;
    }
```

I hope my question is clear, if it **TL;DR** I want to get the first line of a text file separately, then the rest Id like to loop through.

Comment: its simple, read first line save it to some variable then start your loop for next lines separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't advice using a for-loop here, since the file might contain additional lines (e.g. comments or blank lines) to make it more human-readable. By examining the content of each line, you can make your processing more robust against this sort of thing.

```
static public Media[] importMedia(String fileName)
{
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        // Get and process first line:
        String line = reader.readLine(); // <-- Get the first line. You could consider reader as a queue (sort-of), where readLine() dequeues the first element in the reader queue.
        int numberOfItems = Integer.valueOf(line); // <-- Create an int of that line.
        // Do the rest:
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // <-- Each call to reader.readLine() will get the next line in the buffer, so the first time around this will give you the second line, etc. until there are no lines left to read.
        {
             // You will not get the header here, only the rest.
             if(!line.isEmpty() || line.startsWith("#") {
                 // If the line is not empty and doesn't start with a comment character (I chose # here).
                 String[] split = line.split(",");
                 String fileName = split[0];
                 // etc...
             }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This for some reason only goes over the first line...?

Comment: I'll add some additional comments.

Comment: @Cacoon Don't copy paste the code as it is. Change the condition inside the while loop to make it work for you.

Comment: No I understand that, I wasn't blindly copy pasting.
there was a problem with a splitter inside the while loop that I sinced fixed that fixed it, thanks for your help

Comment: Updated the line with split. It was still using an old variable from the code in the question... Woops.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `while` loop to read up to end of file. Read first line and convert it to `int` than loop through.

```
static public Media[] importMedia(String fileName)
{
    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        // Get and process first line:
        int lineNo=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        // Now read upto lineNo            
        for(int i=0; i < lineNo; i++){

            //Do what you need with other lines. 
            String[] values = reader.readLine().split(",");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      //Your exception handling goes here
    }
}
```